# Why does map.merge() not call the remapping function every time?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, hashmap

The Map.merge() documenation says:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is
>   associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value.
>   Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given
>   remapping function, or removes if the result is null. This method may
>   be of use when combining multiple mapped values for a key. For
>   example, to either create or append a String msg to a value mapping.

For example, this code should calculate how many fruits of each type there are in a basket:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> fruitCounts = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> fruitBasket = Arrays.asList(
        "Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Mango", "Orange", "Mango", "Mango");
    for (String fruit : fruitBasket) {
        fruitCounts.merge(fruit, 1/*First fruit of this type*/, (k, v) -> v + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(fruitCounts);
}
```

There are 2 Apples, 3 Mangos, 2 Oranges and 1 Banana but the actual output is:

```
{Apple=2, Mango=2, Orange=2, Banana=1}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is here

```
(k, v) -> v + 1
```

You should be doing

```
(k, v) -> k + v
```

If you check the implementation of merge it says, `remappingFunction.apply(oldValue, value);` means the existing value will be the first parameter in which you should add the same number you initialized it with which comes as a second parameter for that function.

**Update**

Comment: Note that `(k, v) -> k + v` can also be expressed as `Integer::sum`, but that’s a matter of taste…

Comment: Will `Integer::sum` be performance improvement if used multiple times? I have `merge()` call 10 times in my code..

Comment: @Mritunjay (k+v) will be old value plus new value. But whats new value ?

Comment: @Nilesh new value is always the second parameter of the `merge` function, in your case 1.

Comment: `(k, v) -> k + v` and `Integer::sum` will have exactly the same performance. The class file might be slightly shorter when you use `Integer::sum`.

Comment: Then please try and replace `(k, v)` by something more expressive like `(ov, nv)` because it's confusing

Answer (score 6):

Completing @Mritunjay answer's, here's an equivalent using `compute` where you might be able to see the difference:

```
fruitCounts.compute(fruit, (k,v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1) //computing over the value
fruitCounts.merge(fruit, 1, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue + 1) //merging over the value
```

Comment: It's not merging over the key, but over the existent value

Comment: It is merging over the value, but the what is very unclear is that instead of doing `value+1`, it has to be `key+1`, which I find very counter-intuitive. That's why I'm saying "over the key" instead.

Comment: Sure. The thing is that it is not the key, but the value that's already in the map. Using `(k, v) ->` is what is confusing. If instead you were using `(oldValue, newValue) ->`, everything would be more clear.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: to be fair, the JRE developers [made the same mistake](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040892) when implementing `Collectors.toMap(…)` (the one without a merge function), reporting the old value as duplicate key.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner ooohhh, I didn't know that. I'll change it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Holger how do you manage to find such things? :) Thanks for the link